# Event on First Load

Tags: event-observer

I want to set some data may be in the cookies when visitor first load the website URL. The url can be any. It can be a category page, product page etc. Is there any event so that I can set that data in cookie?

Can I use `controller_front_init_before` event?

Comment: you can set cookie using javascript onload function.Just put this script in header.phtml

Comment: @keyur. it may involve some php code also. SO I need an event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding `controller_front_init_before` is not the best way for setting a cookie as you can miss some redirects and also you have a minimal data in your disposal.

I would recommend using `controller_front_send_response_before` as the last event triggered before output is sent to browser.

Comment: Thanks Tom. It worked. But I want to perform some php action also. With this event the action is performed after the page load completely. That I do not want as I want to submit form action before page gets load.

Comment: Then you have to be more concrete in your question.