# Create Observer to set session before site loads

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, session

I have created a new module :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
 <modules>
   <Net_Customobservers>
       <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
     </Net_Customobservers>
 </modules>
 </config>
```

In app\local\Net\Customobserver\etc\config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Net_Customobservers>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
</Net_Customobservers>
 </modules>
    <global>
      <events>
    <controller_front_send_response_before>
        <observers>
            <custom_observer>
                <class>customobservers/observer</class>
                <method>setUsertype</method>
            </custom_observer>
        </observers>                
      </controller_front_send_response_before>
       </events>

      </global>
     </config>
```

In app\local\Net\Customobserver\model\Observer.php :

```
  class Customobservers_Model_Observer
 {
   public function setUsertype($observer = null)
   {
    echo '1';
   }
 }
```

I need to set session in this method to set usertyp, but it doesn't come here though Module is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Net_Customobservers>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
</Net_Customobservers>
 </modules> 
      <frontend>
      <events>
    <controller_front_send_response_before>
        <observers>
            <custom_observer>
                <class>Net_Customobservers_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>setUsertype</method>
            </custom_observer>
        </observers>                
      </controller_front_send_response_before>
       </events>
         </frontend> 
     </config>
```

Observer :

```
<?php class Net_Customobservers_Model_Observer
 {
   public function setUsertype(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
    $getSession =Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyValue();
    if($getSession == ''){
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyValue('test');
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: But do you think this is correct event controller_front_send_response_before to set session ?

Comment: Yes it is fine For this

Comment: But as per my understanding , it will set session just before sending response, but controller will be already loaded ,right? Is ther any alternate event for this?

Comment: For event you can refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616489/magento-event-on-any-page-load

Comment: I added this event because of : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11239/event-on-first-load

Comment: If answer is useful for you please accept :)

Comment: Always Welcome :)